# List<Object> and SqlRowSet downcasting

Tags: java, spring

I have a question about the downcasting in Java:

`List<Object> values = this.reportDao.retrieveRecord(ACCEPTABLE_DIFF_SQL, diff);`

Code shown above will retrieve the records from Database and assign it to a List called `values`

The method `retrieveRecord()` will loop over the `SqlRowSet` like this:

```
public List<Object> retrieveRecord(String sql, Object[] inputs) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    SqlRowSet rset;
    if (inputs.length == 0) {
        rset = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql);
    } else {
        rset = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql, inputs);
    }

    int colCount = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    if (rset.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            list.add(rset.getObject(i));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

My question is:

If I want to get every column in each row set stored in the `values`, may I have statements like this:

```
SqlRowSet srs = (SqlRowSet) values.get(i);
String str = srs.getString(0); // get first column in the row set.
String str1 = srs.getString(1); // get second column in the row set
```

here `i` stands for the index of the row (we will have one or more rows in the result set)

Comment: From your code I see that you are storing each column values in `values` list. So you can't get a `SqlRowSet` from that list

Comment: @Helios Yeah, I agree with you, but is there any way that I can get the single row, and access the row columns/values in that row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that but I would pick two of it.

1. First returning the `SqlRowSet` directly instead of doing list manipulation. Directly using the getString to get the values in caller code.
2. Slightly longer way but all logic would stay in DAO itself:

   **Code Example:**

   ```
   public  Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> retrieveRecord(String sql, Object[] inputs) {

   Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> mapOfResults = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Object>>();

    SqlRowSet rset;
    if (inputs.length == 0) {
       rset = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql);
    } else {
       rset = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sql, inputs);
    }
    int colCount = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    int rowIndex = 1;
    while (rset.next()) {

       Map<String, Object> columnValueMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
           columnValueMap.put(rset.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i), rset.getObject(i));
       }

       mapOfResults.put(rowIndex, columnValueMap); //now you can access valueMap using index.
       rowIndex++;
    }
       return mapOfResults;
   }
   ```

Comment: It seems the original version of retrieveRecord() assume the data return from the query has exactly one record/row, and the List<Object> only store the columns in a single row right?

Comment: no it's slightly different. As in the original version you can't get the row details using the index and as you know list retrieval doesn't follow any order so you don't anyway to know which column value you are going to get. Map solves both the issues.

Comment: I know what you mean by using the Map, that's pretty reasonable, however,  in the original version, the ```rset.next()``` only execute once, there will be only one rowset out there.